# UILabel size change suddenly when parent UIView animate  

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, size, uilabel

I want to send a subview out of my super `UIView` with animation, It works fine but when i tried to change the size during animation any `UILabel` that i have in my subview suddenly become too small. 
here is part of my code

```
-(void)pushOutScreen:(UIViewController *)pop{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                 animations:^{

                     CGRect frame = pop.view.frame;
                     frame.size.height = frame.size.height /4;
                     frame.size.width = frame.size.width /4;
                     frame.origin.x = -500;
                     frame.origin.y = 318;

                     pop.view.frame = frame;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
}
```

note: any `UIButton` or `UIImage` that is inside my subview animated well but i have only problem with `UILabel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView` animation is not good option for doing this, instead of it try `CAKeyframeAnimation`. This is sample code for scaling `UIView`:

```
- (void) scaleView:(UIView *)popView {
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation
                                  animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    animation.delegate = self;

    // CATransform3DMakeScale has 3 parameter (x,y,z)
    CATransform3D scale1 = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0, 1);
    CATransform3D scale2 = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.2, 0.2, 1);

    NSArray *frameValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale1],
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale2],
                        nil];
    [animation setValues:frameValues];

    NSArray *frameTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                       nil];    
    [animation setKeyTimes:frameTimes];

    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.duration = 1.0;

    [popView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"popup"];
}
```

you can use this after you add your `UIView` as `subView` then you can call this method as scale it. for push out a sub view with this method you need to use `removeFromSubView` after the animation finished. 
for knowing that when it finished use

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I hope it be useful!

Comment: Thank Dude, at last some one answered my problem. the solution you have written was correct. I just edit it a little that be exact to my question and answer.

Comment: but a question what is `animation.fillMode` do in this code?? I still wonder

Comment: `forwards` is equivalent to existing `frozen`, `backwards` clamps time values before zero to zero, `both` clamps time values at both ends of the object's time space!

Comment: Yeah, I also found this text: The fillMode property of the timing protocol defines how an animation will be displayed outside of its active duration. The animation can be frozen at its starting position, at its ending position, both, or removed entirely from display. The default behavior is to remove the animation from display when it has completed.